# Generating a Random String Array

Tags: java

I need help creating a random array of strings with 2 parameters:

1. Length of array
2. Number of characters in each string

Would I need a nested for loop?

Anything would help, thanks!

Comment: "Would I need a nested for loop?" Yes.

Comment: one loop for the String[] and an inner loop for each char[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using nested loop, as you said in the question:

```
 public String[] randomArrayString(int length, int numberOfChar) {
    Random random = new Random();
    char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    String[] array = new String[length];
    String str;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        str = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfChar; j++) {
            str+= chars[random.nextInt(chars.length - 1)];
        }
        array[i] = str;
    }
    return array;
}
```

You can make a solution also using Java 8 Streams, like this:

```
public Object[] randomArrayString(int length, int numberOfChar){
    Random random = new Random();
    char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    return Stream.generate(() -> {
        String str="";
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChar; i++) {
            str+= chars[random.nextInt(chars.length - 1)];
        }
        return str;
    }).limit(length).toArray();
}
```

Comment: These will create a lot of string objects.

Comment: I agree with your opinion, I edited my solution with Java 8 Stream and I hope it is better now. Thank you!

Comment: I don’t really approve of this step towards turning Stack Overflow into a code writing service. I prefer to think that it’s a question and answer site.